# mac equivalent to unix comands

Tags: macos, ubuntu, command-line

I a working through a class project(command line operations are the the purpose of the project), OS was never specified but it seems that the command line commands are meant for Ubuntu. Are there mac equivilent to these commands?

sudo -S apt-get install -y -f

wget

Comment: I just found that curl -O might replace wget. But what is apt-get

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming related questions, not general operating system support. This question is more suited for [su]. Voting to close and migrate there instead. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As titaniumdecoy said, `Homebrew` is the package manager of choice for OSX (`apt-get` is the package manager that Ubuntu uses).

For `wget`, you can either used `curl` to accomplish what you want, or you can simply install Homebrew, then:

```
$ brew install wget
```

Many standard programs such as `date` or `sed` work a bit differently on Mac and Linux as well. I find it's easiest just to grab the Gnu (Linux) versions through Homebrew to keep things consistent across platforms:

```
$ brew install coreutils
$ brew install gnu-sed
```

(sed  is seperate from the rest for some reason)

Answer (score 2):

[MacPorts](http://macports.org) is another popular package manager for Mac OS X.

There is a nice and short comparison of Homebrew with MacPorts at http://deephill.com/macports-vs-homebrew/. The main points are that HomeBrew generally does not require you to add `sudo`, and that `MacPorts` requires XCode and a specific X11 to be installed first, but has *many more* packages.

Answer (score 1):

[Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) is a great package manager for mac.